# Derivation of an integral equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, integral-equations, tomography

I have the following system

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(a(x)\frac{du}{dx}\right)=f, \text{ for } x \in (0,1)$$
with boundary conditions $u_x(0)=0$ and $u(1)=0$. For $a(x)>0$, and $b(x)=\frac{1}{a(x)}$, I am required to obtain an integral equation of the form $u(x)=\int_0^1 k(x,y)b(y)dy$. I have no idea about f

It seems that using the fundamental theorem of calculus two times to integrate the given equation yields something confusing, which doesn't match what is required to be obtained.

I am not able to get past this, after the first step of integration:

$$a(x)\frac{du}{dx}=\int_0^xf(t)dt $$

Any ideas?

Comment: You're almost there: $u(1)-u(x)=\int_{x}^{1}b(v)\int_0^v f(u)du dv$ gives $u(x)=-\int_x^1 b(v)\int_0^v f(u)du dv$. The last double integral is an integral over a 2d region. Integrate over the region in the opposite directions, and you'll have it.

Comment: Aah I got it. However, to get the integral from 0 to 1, the introduction of a step function did the trick.

Comment: Excellent. Using step functions is also a good trick for interchanging orders of integration without drawing pictures, too. I make fewer mistakes that way.